# two-column layout with relative width?

Tags: css

I have a two column layout, using a container and a div called "left" and a div called "Right". How do I make sure that the div#right is only 500px, but div#left is as big as the user's browser will allow ...?

Here's what I have now:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" style="float:left"> </div>
  <div id="right" style="float: right; width: 500px"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only use float on the main element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change style of you left `div` to:

```
<div id="left" style="margin-right:500px"></div>
```

This will make sure that content won't flow under the right floating `div` when content in the left one takes more vertical space than content in the right one.

### Important

Don't forget to put the floated `div` in front of the unfloated one. So put your right one first in the markup and then the left one.

### Solution to your particular problem

So you have two `div` elements

```
<div id="endants-content">
    <div id="screenshot-preview">...</div>
    <div id="endants-main-content">...</div>
</div>
```

And CSS should be like this to make it work as expected:

```
div#endants-content
{
    /* put min-width here is you need it */
}

div#screenshot-preview
{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}

div#endants-main-content
{
    margin-right:30%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: @Zachary Burt: Check my edited answer that solves your particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

Don't float the left div to the left. If you leave it "unfloated", then it will be the main content and automatically fill the available space.

Comment: Is it possible to guarantee the left column a minimum width? I feel like now it's crushing the left column too for some reason, and leaving a bunch of extra space on the right.

Comment: Yes, there is a CSS min-width attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by unfloating the #left div and giving it a padding-left that equals the #right div's width (this makes room for the right div).  Finally, you'd need to swap the source order of both div's.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right" style="float: right; width: 100px; "> </div>
    <div id="left" style="padding-right: 100px; "> </div>
</div>
```

You can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKaDP/1/).

Comment: It's giving me a weird result though. Pasting your code works fine in a solo page, but check out what it's doing in the context of my entire page:

http://skitch.com/zacharyburt/dqhch/destroy-automatic-negative-thoughts

Comment: Do you mean how if you resize too small the #right column overlaps the content?  You can fix that by setting a `min-width` on the #left column, which you'll have to hack with a CSS expression if you care about it working in IE6.